# Empty Geofabrik Shapefile data

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, geofabrik

I downloaded Switzerland OSM data from Geofabrik.de at https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/switzerland.html especially the `switzerland-latest-free.shp.zip` file.

The MD5 sum corresponds to what's specified (`293b013ec4d5574cbe3dad703f18acdf`).

But after extracting the files, when I load a [Shapefile](https://www.esri.com/content/dam/esrisites/sitecore-archive/Files/Pdfs/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf), e.g. in QGIS, it shows an empty attribute table:

[image]

Did I miss something there? Do I need to preprocess the file in some way to make the features visible?

EDIT: same thing happens if I try to load the Shapefile with [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/):

```py
>>> import geopandas as gpd
>>> gdf = gpd.open('./switzerland-latest-free.shp/gis_osm_pois_a_free_1.shp')

>>> gdf
Empty GeoDataFrame
Columns: [geometry]
Index: []
```

Comment: I did check the data and there is a problem with this Switzerland data extract (I get the same result as you : the shapefile load in QGIS but with 0 feature...) other country work as expected. You may try later after geofabrik update the data or look for another source...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many of the shapefiles from that download are empty. The .shp files are 100 bytes long, which is basically just the shapefile header. There are large .shp files in that download but they don't have a .shx file to go with them. They also report zero features with `ogrinfo`.

I just tried Liechtenstein as a comparison and that looked okay, so something is wrong with Switzerland.

Checked the GeoFabrik twitter account and there's the answer:

https://twitter.com/geofabrik/status/1566763301350014977?s=20&t=s31oYR4bdzOstiYDDYFMkA

> "Some of our free shape files on http://download.geofabrik.de were
> tripped up by the unexpected appearance of
> https://openstreetmap.org/node/10000000000 (DBF field width for
> osm_id: 10)... fix being deployed."

Comment: Ah thanks for that piece of information. Hopefully it will get fixed soon.

Comment: The issue seems to be fixed now. Btw, the number of nodes in OSM reached a nice amount... ;)